# How do we prove that weak continuity implies strong continuity? A question concerning an argument in Yosida's book

Tags: functional-analysis

In Yosida's book "Functional analysis" in page 234 one reads:
[image]

I don' t understand the argument here.

he approximates $x(\tau)$ by finitely valued functions $x_n(\tau)$?

How does he deduce that the right hand side goes to zero?

Context: using The uniform boundedness theorem plus the weak continuity of $\{T_t\}$ we arrived at $\sup_{t}\|T_t\| < M$.

Plus using the  weak continuity and the boundedness of $x(t) := T(t)x_0$ one proves that the integral $\int_a^b x(s)\, ds$ is well defined and 
$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \int_a^b x(s + \epsilon)\, ds \to \int_a^b x(s)\, ds $

It seems that we can write instead of what he did

$$(\beta - \alpha)\|x(\xi \pm \epsilon) - x(\xi)\|\leq \sup_{\alpha \leq \eta \leq \beta}\|T_\eta\|\cdot \|\int_{\xi - \beta}^{\xi - \alpha}x(\tau \pm \epsilon) -x(\tau)\, d\tau\| \xrightarrow[\epsilon \to 0]{}0 $$

So here we don't  need to use finitely valued functions to approximate $x(\tau)$

Is the above argument correct?

How can we prove this result using finitely valued functions to approximate $x(\tau)$?

Comment: $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \int_a^b x(s + \epsilon)\, ds \to \int_a^b x(s)\, ds$.
What is your dominat in this case for interchanging the integral with the limes?

Comment: this follows from the uniform boundedness of $T_s$ for $s \leq T$. Remember that $x(t) = T_t x_0 $ I didn't point this out on the question, but it is in the book. The convergence depends also on the theory of integration on Banach spaces... its a bit involved but the point is that he argues using finite approximations... and that I fail to see.